# How to use tmutil delete on Big Sur, APFS

Tags: time-machine, apfs, big-sur

I'm using macOS 11 Big Sur and APFS. I sometimes want to remove old backups to save space. I don't want Time Machine taking up the entire external drive.

```
% tmutil listbackups
2020-10-18-001052.backup
2020-11-06-124150.backup
2020-11-15-173211.backup

% sudo tmutil delete 2020-10-18-001052.backup
Total deleted: Zero KB
```

I think I have to pass a "path" to `tmutil delete`. How do I get the path? Or how do I otherwise delete one of the backups listed by `tmutil listbackups`?

Answer (score 11):

The Big Sur syntax changed, but you need to specify the volume and the timestamp with -d and -t:

```
sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/Time\ Machine -t 2020-11-18-100936
```

You don't need to specify the Backups.backupdb folder or the backup machine.  I had done `tmutil setdestination /Volumes/Time\ Machine` previously (where **Time Machine** is the name of your drive.)

Comment: I don't know what to think now, because Apple Tech Support told me that I could not delete Time Machine backups, because it would 'corrupt' the database. I wonder if some of the people in tech support don't know their own product.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get ``(null): No such file or directory``

Comment: @UVV Do you have spaces in your volume name?  Perhaps try "/Volume/My Backup Drive" - replacing My Backup Drive inside of quotes.  In the example above I escaped the space...

Comment: Nope, see my other cross-post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252329699

Comment: I would be interested in your comments to my tentative answer which is too long to be a comment.

Comment: Apple Support is wrong. You can delete backups. In the past this wasn't the case, but it's true now.

Comment: I bumped on the same issue yesterday, I run `sudo tmutil delete -d "/Volumes/Time Machine" -t 2021-02-28-133913` but I got `(null): Operation not permitted (error 1)` :(

Comment: I also tried by granting full disk access in Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy, but still, same. I think the only option is to erase the disk and start over, or buy a new one and keep that as archive (if there are needed data).

Comment: @panosru I would have thought giving the terminal full disk access in privacy tab of Security & Privacy in System Preferences would do the trick.  (Also, /Volumes/Time Machine was a fictitious name... just confirming you replacedit with the name of your actual drive... can you do ls -al "/Volumes/<my drive>"?)

Comment: @AdamMorris yes I named "Time Machine" my external drive, after a lot of searching I gave up and just formatted my drive again, then re-assigned it to be used as a time machine drive. It seems that with APFS you can't remove backups, at least I couldn't find any way.

Answer (score 5):

N.B. the `tmutil` manpage is sorely in need of an update since the changes starting with macOS 11 Big Sur.

> Cf. @Tetsujin 's post

to delete an APFS timemachine backup snapshot, this works in macOS 12.1 monterey:

```
  # sw_vers              # print macOS version information

  ProductName:    macOS
  ProductVersion: 12.1
  BuildVersion:   21C52
```

for APFS timemachine backups, what the tmutil `delete` verb requires is the:

- backup mount point in [ `/Volumes/mountpoint` ] format
- timestamp in [ `yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss` ]  format

note: per the manpage, the [ `-p path` ] option is for HFS volumes only.

one can find the current mountpoint using the `machinedirectory` verb:

```
  # tmutil machinedirectory

  /Volumes/tm
```

and/or `destinationinfo` verb:

```
  # tmutil destinationinfo

  > ==================================================
  Name          : tm
  Kind          : Local
  Mount Point   : /Volumes/tm
  ID            : 6E28F286-DA89-4D4E-8AA3-5B7D831D3C6C
```

use the `listbackups` verb to list the existing snapshot timestamps

```
  # tmutil listbackups

  2021-12-27-184808.backup
  2021-12-28-181718.backup
  ...
  2022-01-07-180623.backup
  2022-01-08-095245.backup
```

so, now craft the command per above requirements:

```
  # tmutil delete -d /Volumes/tm -t 2021-12-28-181718

  1 backups deleted
```

pfbbt, bob's your uncle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This, this is the first working answer I found! Thank you. Totally unclear that the 'mountpoint' is something completely different than the mountpoint in `/Volumes/.timemachine` 

`tmutil machinedirectory` was the magic needed.

Now the only weird thing is that `tmutil listbackups` does not show the backups, but when I enter Time Machine it still shows the deleted backups. Let's call that a Sonoma mishap (of which there are many).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the combination of `-d` and `-t`, you can also use the `-p` parameter to provide the full path to the backup (if you know it):

```
tmutil delete [-d backup_mount_point -t timestamp] [-p path]
```

This works for me:

```
sudo tmutil delete -p /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/macbook/2021-04-03-123111/
```

This is on macOS Big Sur 11.3.

Comment: I don't think this can work with an APFS format TM disk.

Comment: It worked for me either: `sudo tmutil delete -p /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backups/Backups.backupdb/ + [your computer name] + / + [timestamp]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty tentative answer, but too much for a comment...

Big Sur & Time Machine on APFS will always require the entire volume. You can't do anything other - see [APFS changes in Big Sur: how Time Machine backs up to APFS, and more](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/29/apfs-changes-in-big-sur-how-time-machine-backs-up-to-apfs-and-more/)

> APFS doesn’t support directory hard links, so can’t use the same mechanism when storing Time Machine backups. Instead, what appears to function as a form of virtual file system is created using new features in APFS.
> The volume assigned the role of Backup appears to be a regular APFS volume, and is protected from normal access, even by root.

I have to admit I cannot investigate this myself to confirm, I don't have a Big Sur-capable Mac here.

Comment: Okay, but what does that mean for `tmutil delete`? They're storing the backups differently on APFS, but they should still be able to implement the delete function.

Comment: If the entire volume is a] protected even from root & b] cannot be used for any other purpose… what's the point of trying to take manual control of the process? If you want a smaller backup footprint, save it to a smaller volume.

Comment: Apparently APFS volumes do not have a maximum size by default. It will just expand to take all available space, even though there are other volumes on the disk. I don't see a way in disk utility (so far) to add a max size limit to my existing volume. So, as it is now, Time Machine will take over my entire drive and I can't stop it, which is ridiculous.

Comment: Also, the volume is _not_ protected by access from root. I just created and deleted a test file at the root of the volume. There may be some confusion around this point on the internet, because certain commands in Terminal (eg, `sudo touch test-file.txt`) will fail if you haven't enabled Full Disk Access for Terminal in System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more complex than that of @Adam Morris, but with some differences. On refection I think the complexities are not needed and that @Adam Morris's answer is correct and sufficient.  I'm leaving this answer (which I believe to be correct) in case it is useful to others.

`man tmutil` says that the command is:

`tmutil delete [-d backup_mount_point -t timestamp ...] [path ...]`

What is the mount point? There are two steps:

1. With Finder look in the snapshot's volume on the Time Machine disk.
2. List the mount point with the command `mount`. This includes lines like this:

`com.apple.TimeMachine.2020-12-08-145707.backup@/dev/disk10s2 on /Volumes/.timemachine/8A653E1B-09C0-44C1-9F6C-EF28F0F7A087/2020-12-08-145707.backup (apfs, local, read-only, journaled, nobrowse)`

So I have tried the command:

`sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/.timemachine/8A653E1B-09C0-44C1-9F6C-EF28F0F7A087/2020-12-08-145707.backup -t 2020-12-08-145707`

The immediate response is: `Total deleted: Zero KB` and the folder on the TM drive has gone.

But has the backup really gone?  I am not sure!!

So my suggestion is that the command should be like this:

`sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/.timemachine/<UUID>/<date-time>.backup -t <date-time>`

where the UUID and date-time are from running the `mount` command.

Answer (score 0):

My approach today in M1 macOS Monterey

FYI, when your time machine disk is about to be full and you don't have a new disk to be appended.

```bash
$ tmutil listbackups -d /Volumes/timemachine
2021-09-19-165426.backup
2021-09-30-113009.backup
2021-10-13-130955.backup
2021-10-20-185257.backup
...

$ sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/timemachine -t 2021-09-19-165426
(null): Resource busy (error 16)

# reboot macOS

$ sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/timemachine -t 2021-09-19-165426
1 backups deleted
```