# find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory

Tags: macos

Running this command `sudo find / -iname *.app`, among the entries returned was:

```
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please limit your questions to one question per question so that they can be found easily. [Here's an answer to your second question.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39287/how-can-i-manually-delete-old-backups-to-free-space-for-time-machine) Also, try to be specific with your question title so that the question can be found by others.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo find -x / -iname *.app
```

or

```
sudo find / -iname *.app 2>/dev/null
```

The first solution prevents `find` from descending into directories that have a device number different that that of the file from which the decent began. This prevents the errors from occurring, but limits the search to a single device.

The second solution does not stop the error messages from being generated. Instead, the message are just discarded so you do not see them. This solution discards not only the error messages you describe, but rather all error messages.

Comment: It might be useful to the OP to explain what's going on, and how each of these fixes the issue.

Comment: @forquare: Is my updated answer sufficient?

Comment: it's much better 

Answer (score 1):

The errors indicate the problem. It states that /dev/fd/3 and /dev/fd/4 are not directories, because they're not, even though they appear to be directories.

> The files /dev/fd/_ through /dev/fd/# refer to file descriptors which can be accessed through the file system.

<sup>Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/fd.4.html</sup>

Comment: The linked page no longer exist, the closest I could find to your answer is this https://man.openbsd.org/stdin.4. Can you revisit the answer pls?