# What do I do if Time Machine says "Waiting" to view a particular backup?

Tags: time-machine

I have this happening on a Yosemite machine with a backup residing on another Yosemite machine.

[image]

Other backups further forward in time work fine. My desire is to delete this backup, but I can't because as long as it says "Waiting" there's no "Delete backup" option.

Comment: Not really a soloution but I found that just straight up waiting 10 minutes for it to load let me however in my case I actually wanted to restore it not delete it.

Comment: So it's really doing something. I never had the patience to wait that long. Sounds like a real solution to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete a backup via the `sudo tmutil delete` command. You'll need administrative privileges to do this:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type in `sudo tmutil delete` (including end space, but *don't* press enter yet!)
3. Go to Finder, open your TM Drive, and open the `Backups.backupdb` folder
4. Open your Machine
5. You'll need to find the folder containing the backup you want to delete.
6. Drag and drop the folder containing the backup you want to delete into Terminal.
7. Your Terminal should say `sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/TM\ Drive/Backups.backupdb/Mac/2014...` (backslashes are included before spaces)
8. Now press enter. You'll need to type you user password (it won't be displayed).