# Emptying the trash after deleting Time Machine Backups

Tags: macos, time-machine, high-sierra

I went to my Time Machine External HD and deleted one of the backups by dragging it to the trash. Now when I try to empty the trash I keep getting messages that certain folders can't be deleted because they are in use. How do I empty the trash completely? I tried opening the trash and right-clicking on the folder and choosing "Delete Immediately" but it still gives me the message that folder can't be deleted.  I'm running High Sierra 10.13.5 on an iMac.

Comment: How about turning Time Machine off before nuking a Time Machine backup ?

Comment: When you say you "deleted one of the backups", what exactly do you mean? Are you talking about deleting the entire Backups.backupdb folder, one of the per-computer folders inside that (i.e. all backups from a particular computer), one of the timestamped folders inside one of those (i.e. a snapshot), or some file or folder within one of those?

Comment: I wasn't making a backup. My backups are scheduled for after 1:00 am. The backup folder I deleted was about in the middle of my backups. Several months ago.

Comment: @GordonDavisson. Yes. My backups are in a folder named Backups.backupdb. In that folder are several folders named with the date and time of the backup. I moved one of these dated folders into the trash.  I was just testing how to delete certain backups.

Comment: In that case, I recommend putting the snapshot back, and then using the "Delete Backup" option within the Time Machine interface. See [this previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39287/how-can-i-manually-delete-old-backups-to-free-space-for-time-machine/58218#58218)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't move folder back into the backup folder. It gives me the message backup items can't be modified!  I moved folder out of trash and just moved it onto the Time Machine disk at the same level as Backups.backupdb.

Comment: Are you doing "incremental backups"? If so, you may have effectively trashed all of them - this would be worth checking...

Comment: It was set to do backups once a week.  I'll check if my other backups are there. Thanks.

Comment: @SolarMike My older backups are still there but how do I determine if they are valid.  Oh, Backup no longer works after my idiot move.

Comment: I have exactly the same question and same phenomena: can't empty or restore the trash. There are some solutions saying that we have to reformat the backup disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the problem only shows when I want to empty my trash and my related Time Machine volume is mounted. When I want to delete my trash, I temporarily unmount the TM Volume. And from now on I will not try to make extra room on my other TM back-up volumes by deleting folders from my Time Machine back-up. I will either let Time Machine automatically delete what is needed when the volume is full, or manually delete data using a method built into the Time Machine software.